# is it possible to limit access to website to specific computer?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip

Note: I am not asking how to limit asking to a site by means of a static IP address, this is already done in my .htaccess file. I have a particular site I will need to access on the road often but will only be doing so from a particular machine.

In short, is it possible to limit access to a particular website based on something specific within a pc other than IP?

Comment: Can you use persistant cookie?

Comment: @webarto - sounds like a viable option but how might I load the cookie onto the portable machine if I don't ever have access to the site in the first place (due to the IP restriction)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up SSL on the web server and authenticate to it using a certificate that only exists on that particular machine.

Have a look at [this article](http://monduke.com/2006/06/04/the-fifteen-minute-guide-to-mutual-authentication/) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Pehaps you could manually create a cookie just for you and then your site will let you in?

Answer (score 0):

do authentications on the site..quick form that requires a specific username and password, once its set, create a session that keeps the information.. all the pages you dont want others to see just check if the session is present if not send them to the login form..

Comment: already do this. I am looking for something even more fool proof than this if possible. I do not want to have a single page "accidentally" leave off the session validated check and allow access to the site

Comment: @JM4: then use a persistent cookie with a long and "impossible-to-guess" name, basically a passphrase. You can have apache check for that cookie' presence before PHP ever gets involved, and redirect to a login page or simply deny access outright. Since the cookie check is done at the webserver level, it'd be impossible to access any content in the site unless the cookie is present, and if it's 'impossible-to-guess', you've effectively got a bank vault for a front door.

Comment: @Marc B - thanks for the suggestion - any good articles on this? Most I have found deal with asp.net. Without access to the site in the first place, I assume I'd have to temporarily open up site access to all IP addresses first?

Comment: @JM4 don't know off. checking for a cookie in Apache is easy enough with mod_rewrite and the like. but yeah, you'd most likely have to open up access globally temporarily so you can get in and have the cookie set, unless you want to somehow hack it into your browser's cookie cache.