# Can I use PHP to limit a page only on a set of IPs?

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, ip

I have a folder which contains an admin panel - no password or session management is on the script. The URL is complex to get too. To save time before making an admin login system. Can I restrict a folder and all sub folders and files via .`htaccess` or should I make a PHP include which checks an Array list of IPs and then just does `die()` or redirect `Header()` to external source?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could do either if it were a page you really weren't that concerned about. If it's an actual critical page put forward the effort to build in some real security. Complex URL's are NOT security.

Comment: Pretty bad idea but array would be more convenient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range
You should find a solution here.

Comment: it may create problem when you are out of your personal computer

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589638/is-it-possible-to-limit-access-to-website-to-specific-computer

Comment: +1 to @RickCalder. A basic password and session system is trivial to implement, and should be considered a bare minimum for this kind of thing. If you're writing something complex enough to need an admin panel, then you're already doing more work than that, so I don't get why you wouldn't implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.htaccess` sure will be easier since you don't have to write a wrapper around any non-php file that might exists in your directories.

You will first `Deny from all` and then use `Allow from ip.ip.ip.ip` to allow a certain ip to get access, repeat step #2 as many times as neccessary.

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all

Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.1.13
```

---

Using PHP you could check whether `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is in your array of valid ips, if so grant the user access... otherwise; HALT!

```
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array ('127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.13')) == false) {
  die ('restricted access');
}
```

<sup>post written and edited using my blackberry, sorry for any minor errors (including formatting)</sup>

Comment: Running that .htaccess I get a 500 Internal Service Error

Comment: The example snippet should be correct, though the post is written using my blackberry - check out this link for more information; http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html